# Is there a way to store stage luggage until needed?

Tags: luggage-storage, shipping

I'm an artist/DJ that is looking to travel soon.  I'm a fairly light traveler with the exception of my equipment which is just a little more than I can carry at one time.  I don't have any gigs scheduled per se. But if an opportunity were to arise, It would be nice to have my equipment available.  I was wondering if there was a way to ship my equipment for storage until I needed it. When I do need my equipment, I could request that it gets shipped to a specified address.

**Is there such a service? Or is this merely a business plan?**

As a side note, I don't have anybody within my reach that I can trust to have my stuff shipped in a timely fashion.

Comment: Could you maybe specify a region of the world where you want to do this? This would make it easier to research an answer for the question, now it's quite broad. Also a price range might be helpful. With enough money you can ship (almost) anything to (almost) anywhere.

Comment: The two areas I was looking at were West Europe (starting in UK going east) or East Asia (Taiwan, Philippines, and Hong Kong).  Got friends and family in both areas.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a solution for you but only an additional warning: If you want to move expensive professional equipment outside of the EU, you need to worry about customs and import duties. The ATA Carnet might be a solution but you need a detailed schedule and a possibly not insignificant sum of money as a collateral.

Comment: How many m3 of stuff do you have? If the money permits, having an ISO container of stuff that you can just send well, wherever maybe the best plan.  Not sure how much moving a TEU (Twenty-foot Equivalent Unit) costs on the spot market, though...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have never used their service, or that of a competitor, but [PODS](http://www.pods.com/) (Portable On-Demand Storage) might do what you want.  The big questions will be cost, and timeliness. I also don't know if they have service outside of the U.S., but there may be similar services elsewhere in the world.

The service, as I understand it, essentially delivers a large "pod" (metal crate) to your drive way, where you can load whatever you want.  It is then stored in one of their storage facilities, and can later be dropped off again--at whichever address you specify, including one across the country.

As the service is intended for long-term storage, and cross-country moves, it may prove to be un-economical as a sort of "on-demand luggage" service, but it might be worth investigating.

Comment: This sounds like something ISO containers would be good for...just a matter of pricing I suppose