# Storage that ships belongings to location

Tags: planning, luggage-storage

Is there a service (obviously paid) in which you can ship containers to specific address and the will be indexed and stored in a facility.

Then ideally when you need the containers you give them your address and they will attempt to expedite them to you as fast as possible?

Ideally such a service could be based around some of the large airports in the US (similar to Amazon's distributions centers) so you could get 1-2 day delivery speeds.

Now some may argue that his doesn't relate to travel, but imagine how convenient it would be to log onto either a website or dial a phone and get your goods (or replacement goods) with in a couple days.  Perfect if you lose your goods while traveling.

Comment: How will you know what _goods_ will be lost in advance to store them? doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @HaLaBi Well most people have a laptop, some clothes, a cell phone and couple other goods.  I intentionally made the question pretty vague so that it is up for interpretation.  No matter how prepared you might be I think the service could be useful.

Comment: If you mean a package rather than a [container](http://www.worldshipping.org/about-the-industry/how-liner-shipping-works/the-step-by-step-process), there is always *[poste restante](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poste_restante)*.

Comment: @HaLaBi Some people are quiet particular with the laptops they use.  ;) For example I new a guy that only use Thinkpads(with pointing sticks).  Not always the easiest thing to get a hold off when you are traveling.

Comment: @choster that looks good except it looks the mail service only holds packages for 30 days and you have to know the final destination in the 1st place

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to store stage luggage until needed?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17833/is-there-a-way-to-store-stage-luggage-until-needed)

Comment: I call these services "family members". :)

Comment: @MichaelHampton Unfortunately my direct family members are  not willing ( well organized enough) and have passed.  Otherwise I would agree, of course I can look get a good friend but that is to easy ;)

Comment: @Flimzy As the answers points that is intended more for long term storage and not short term storage facilities

Answer (score 2):

Some self-storage places, and mailbox services, offer this type of service.  However, they are rarely geared up to handle delivery to multiple countries, so are of limited use for travel.

Examples for smaller packages include [Storage by Mail](http://www.storagebymail.com/) and [Ship 2 Storage](http://www.ship2storage.com/).  For larger amounts up to house size there's people like [Flexistore (UK)](http://www.flexistore.co.uk/), [uBox](http://www.uhaul.com/ubox) and [Pods](http://www.pods.com/).

Probably the best way is to leave the packages with a relative or friend, and get them to ship them to you if needed.  Alternatively, a local mailbox and shipping place in your home country could be another option, if they're flexible enough to just keep a few boxes in the back room and ship them to you worldwide on demand.